# jQuery animation not running as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see, it's two functions calling each other and very simple conditions based on the length of an object.

Here is the weird thing:

1. If 'size' is > 1 when document is loaded or refreshed, the animations work.
2. When it changes from 0 or 1 to > 1 it does not.

The "True" is being printed and snowAPI is being called from `.fadeOut(2000, snowAPI);` but no animation. Help is much appreciated.

HTML

```
<table id="INCtable">
<tr id="head"><th>Priority</th><th>#</th><th>Age</th><th>Time left to breach</th><th>Reassign count</th></tr>
<tr id="content"><td id="prio"><span></span></td><td id="number"><span></span></td><td id="age"><span></span></td><td id="breach"><span></span></td><td id="reass"><span></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
function snowAPI() {
    //Additional things happening
    showNextINC(INClist);
}
function showNextINC(INClist) {

            ++INCindex;
            var size = Object.keys(INClist).length;

        if (size > 1) {
            console.log(true)
            $('#INCtable #content #prio span').text(INClist[INCindex % size].prio)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(2000);
            $('#INCtable #content #number span').text(INClist[INCindex % size].number)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(2000);
            $('#INCtable #content #age span').text(INClist[INCindex % size].age)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(2000);
            $('#INCtable #content #breach span').text(INClist[INCindex % size].breach)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(2000);
            $('#INCtable #content #reass span').text(INClist[INCindex % size].reassCount)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(2000, snowAPI);
        }

        else if (size === 1){
            console.log(true)
            $('#INCtable #content #prio').text(INClist[0].prio)
            $('#INCtable #content #number').text(INClist[0].number)
            $('#INCtable #content #age').text(INClist[0].age)
            $('#INCtable #content #breach').text(INClist[0].breach)
            $('#INCtable #content #reass').text(INClist[0].reassCount)
            setTimeout(snowAPI, 8000);
        }
        else if (size === 0) {
            console.log(true)
            setTimeout(snowAPI, 8000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is `#INCtable #content #prio span` **HTML** id's property and is linked to HTML so post a full and verifiable situation.

Comment: Does it loop through too fast to animate?

Comment: I don't think so, it's set to not call the function until the animation is done, right?

Comment: .........Anyone?